# Wampserver: "Can’t select database"

Tags: localhost

I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and had to reinstall WampServer to get it running.

I'd like to reinstall Wordpress for a local WampServer site.

I have deleted the old database and username, and created a new user + associated database of the same name. I left the password blank.

When I try to run the install, I get to `http://ssdhdd/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2` and the error:

> Can’t select database
>
> We were able to connect to the database server
>   (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to
>   select the example database.
>
> Are you sure it exists? Does the user example have permission to use
>   the example database? On some systems the name of your database is
>   prefixed with your username, so it would be like username_example.
>   Could that be the problem?

I have confirmed the database name is correct.

I've confirmed the user has correct privileges to the database + global privileges.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Skype? If so try signing out of Skype. Then restart the WAMP server and check if that helps.

Comment: Thansk @ItsMePN, Skype is not loaded.

Comment: Ah, ok. Sometimes Skype port clashes with WAMP server port. So it could have been the reason. May be someone else will help you out here.

Comment: Another reason why it may not be working is firewall. So please try turning off the windows firewall - if that fixes the problem, then turn it back on, and allow access to TCP/3306(default port).

Comment: I have turned Windows 10 Firewall off, and GlassWire Firewall off, and the problem remains @ItsMePN

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem. Then I realised I had EasyPHP running (I've been trying different web dev solutions). After stopping EasyPHP, I was able to continue with the wordpress installation.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this very same problem.
I finally solved it by using 3308 as the MySQL port.
Was using wampserver Version 3.2.0 - 64bit on Windows 10.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If using wamp server the default db is MariaDB i fixed it by changing the default db to MySQL
Go to wamp tray -> tools -> select Invert default dbms it should now be set to MySQL